# Give Azure DevOps Pipelines access to publish gradle package to Azure DevOps Artifact feed

Tags: azure, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am setting up a shared code library and have managed to build artifacts and publish them to a feed using a personal access token, but I want to move the publishing to an Azure Pipeline. I am trying to use the build account with the access token available at build time (System.AccessToken) but I get a 403 error from Azure Artifacts. The [Project] Build Service ([Org]) account is added as a contributor to the feed.

I have a build.gradle.kts file that has the following config (sensitive info replaced):

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("private") {
            groupId = "[groupId]"
            artifactId = "shared"
            version = "0.0.1"
            artifact("./build/libs/lib.jar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[Org]/[Project]/_packaging/maven-private/maven/v1") {
            name = "maven-private"
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("AZURE_DEVOPS_USER")
                password = System.getenv("AZURE_DEVOPS_ACCESS_TOKEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Azure pipelines config:

```
trigger:
  - main

pr: none

resources:
  - repo: self

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - task: Gradle@2
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
              workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              tasks: 'build'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
          - task: Gradle@2
            env:
              AZURE_DEVOPS_USER: "[Project] Build Service ([Org])"
              AZURE_DEVOPS_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
              workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
              tasks: 'publish'
              javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
```

The publish step fails with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':lib:publishPrivatePublicationToMaven-privateRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'private' to repository 'maven-private'
   > Could not PUT 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[Org]/[Project]/_packaging/maven-private/maven/v1/[groupId]/shared/0.0.1/shared-0.0.1.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden - User '[userId]' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.
```

I have no idea how to proceed with debugging, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Emil Wihlander, have you already tried the following method? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

For the error ' You need to have 'ReadPackages'', you should enter your Azure Artifacts–>your feed–>feed settings–>Permissions。
Depending on your choice scope(organization scope or project scope),

[image]

You should click Add Users/groups and search for Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName}) and add as Contributor for organization-level scoped feed.

Or click Add Users/groups and search for {Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name}) and add as Contributor for project-level scoped feed.

Please see the details in the [Configure permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops) doc.
I hope this could do some help.

[image]